# How to upload bulk images to server with their context using ajax in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, image-uploading, django-2.2

I have been trying add bulk images functionality to the asset uploader.

Here is the model of the images

```
class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None, related_name="create_asset")
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=uuid.uuid4)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,editable = False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    TWODIMENTIONAL = "2D"
    THREEDIMENTIONAL = "3D"
    DESIGN = "DS"
    ASSET_CHOICES = (
        (TWODIMENTIONAL, '2D render'),
        (THREEDIMENTIONAL, '3D render'),
        (DESIGN, 'Designer'),
    )
    asset_type = models.CharField(default=DESIGN,
        max_length=2,
        choices = ASSET_CHOICES,
        verbose_name='Asset Type',
        )
```

how can I add bulk upload to this model with the asset_type.
upload multiple images with their details like type(check boxes) and many other things.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this article - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html ?

settings.py :

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

urls.py :
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base.html:

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Photos Library - Simple is Better Than Complex{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'includes/header.html' %}
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

models.py:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py:
from .models import Photo

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^basic-upload/$', views.BasicUploadView.as_view(), name='basic_upload'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View

from .forms import PhotoForm
from .models import Photo

class BasicUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        photos_list = Photo.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'photos/basic_upload/index.html', {'photos': photos_list})

    def post(self, request):
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

photos/basic_upload/index.html:

```
{% block javascript %}
  {# JQUERY FILE UPLOAD SCRIPTS #}
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>

  {# PHOTOS PAGE SCRIPTS #}
  <script src="{% static 'photos/js/basic-upload.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

photos/basic_upload/index.html:

```
{# 1. BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION #}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
</button>

{# 2. FILE INPUT TO BE USED BY THE PLUG-IN #}
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple
       style="display: none;"
       data-url="{% url 'photos:basic_upload' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

{# 3. TABLE TO DISPLAY THE UPLOADED PHOTOS #}
<table id="gallery" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for photo in photos %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ photo.file.url }}">{{ photo.file.name }}</a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

photos/js/basic-upload.js:

```
$(function () {
  /* 1. OPEN THE FILE EXPLORER WINDOW */
  $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
    $("#fileupload").click();
  });

  /* 2. INITIALIZE THE FILE UPLOAD COMPONENT */
  $("#fileupload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {  /* 3. PROCESS THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER */
      if (data.result.is_valid) {
        $("#gallery tbody").prepend(
          "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td></tr>"
        )
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you @rg_elite will try that and let you know the result.